# Spring Boot App with Mysql database and Microsoft Azure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, azure, connection

I have little problem with deploy Spring Boot Application with MySql on Azure. When i use Eclipse all work fine, but when i deploy on Microsoft Azure, deploying end with success, but i get

```
2021-07-24T09:30:20.876358957Z 2021-07-24 09:30:20.875  INFO 124 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-07-24T09:30:21.830327807Z 2021-07-24 09:30:21.774  INFO 124 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672309649Z 2021-07-24 09:30:22.605 ERROR 124 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672341649Z 
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672346649Z com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672349949Z 
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672352949Z The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-07-24T09:30:22.672356349Z  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql- 
  connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
  2021-07-24T09:30:22.672360049Z    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
```

When I trying enter to app. I was used a lot of tutorial, because i don't know Azure, but this solutions not help me with my problem. If good know this exception, i have problem with url address in my application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{name of database server}.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/{name of scheme}?useSSL=false&useLegacyDateTimeCode=false&serverTimezone=CET
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username={login}@{name my database server}
spring.datasource.password={my password}
```

what do you mean?

Comment: From above it seems your application is not able to establish communication with MySQL server. Can you try to check if the container in which your App is running has outboud ports opened to interact with components outside of running container?

Comment: Sorry, how i can do it?

Comment: @BHeiB enter container with ``docker exec`` command and try to connect mysql ip address with ``telnet`` or ``curl`` command.

Comment: I am totally newest in Azure and i dont 't know how i do your instruction. If i good mean i must instalation Docker on my system? Or use Azure CLI on Azure Portal?